# Retrive form data and display on two pages in php

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and have been given an assignment in which we have to create an about us Website using PHP.

The assignment requires us to create a homepage (as well as 2 other supporting pages) which will ask the user to enter their name in a text box. It is required that there is no submit button and instead the user must only click enter. The next requirement is that when the user continues to the next page it must welcome them by displaying what the user inputted in the text box on the first page. Eg Welcome Greg..

I was able to successfully implement that but it is also required that when the user continues to the final page that it must also welcome them with what was entered in the text box on the homepage. This is what I am having issues with.

My code for the first page is as follows:

Homepage.php:

```
<form action="2ndpage.php" method="post">
      Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>  
</form>
```

2ndPage.php:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!
```

I am unsure on what code is required to get the text entered on the first page to show up on the 3rd and final page called 3rdpage.php

I hope im not to far off and havent confused anyone. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make your $_POST["name"] as a SESSION so that can be used on every page.

Make it like

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["name"];

Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

But make sure you have a logout to destroy the SESSION. Otherwise the $_SESSION will conflict when you login next time..

Comment: Might be worth noting that you need to start the session (*`session_start();`*) if you want them to work at all.

Comment: Thanks guys ill give it a try. Does session start need to be present on every page?

Comment: yeah.. session_start(); should present in every page.

Comment: Do i need to make any changes on the first page? I am recieving errors with the $_POST saying that its undefined?? Sorry for my complete incompetence. Now all its saying is Welcome !

Comment: which page the error showing?? 2ndpage or 3rdpage..??

Comment: I get the error on both pages but if i remove the $_POST['name'] i get no errors but just welcome !. I hope i am making sense

Comment: Change the $_POST["name"]  to $_POST['name']

Comment: Now 2ndpage.php is showing the welcome but the 3rdpage.php is saying that name index is undefined. So confused hahah

Comment: u just remove the $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["name"]; line on the 3rdpage.php

Comment: and use the session_start(); and Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> only

Comment: You are welcome... Don't forget to destroy the session when u want to login again.